# C++ vs Java Arrays

Tags: java, c++

In C++, we can create an array by using stack memory like so:

int arr[100];

In java, we create arrays by always using heap memory like so:

int[] arr = new int[100];

My question is, whenever we declare an array in java inside a method, is this array deallocated once the function goes out of scope? or it is deallocated when the program ends.

Comment: Java doesn't have deterministic deallocation.

Comment: Java has a garbage collector. What we know is that the array is deallocated sometime, or maybe the OS has deals with the "leaked" memory. Or maybe the java compiler does escape analysis and the array is allocated on the stack.

Comment: In the C++ form, the array is allocated on the stack and thus disappears when it leaves scope. Java allocates pretty much everything on the heap, which unfortunately means that almost every variable's lifetime is not tied to the scope in which it was declared.

Comment: Have you searched the internet for ["c++ array vs Java"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+array+versus+java&oq=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+array+versus+java&aqs=chrome..69i57.11295j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)?  There are a lot of similar questions.

Comment: what about the following:  char[] grades = {'A', 'B', 'C'}; (heap or stack?) int 5(heap or stack?) in JAVA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, once the variable goes out of scope, it will be no longer reachable. The garbage collector will eventually reclaim the memory, but you have no guarantees about when that will happen.

But purely from the programmer's perspective, the effects are very similar. Both in C++ and Java, once the variable goes out of scope, the memory is again available to the application.

To learn more about it, I would recommend to search for [manual memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_memory_management) (like in C++) vs [Garbage Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) (like in Java).